# What is the difference in meaning between future simple and present progressive when they express a refusal or a promise

Tags: difference, future-tense

> You can try and kill me, but still, **I'm not telling** you anything!

> You can try and kill me, but still, I **won't tell** you anything!

Do these two sentences have a different meaning? Is *won't tell* stronger? Does it mean *in anytime*, where *not telling* means in the close future, not after?

I read in a grammar book that refusals are expressed by the Future Simple, not Present Progressive.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. The present progressive can be used to imply intention.

Comment: but the fact to choose present progressive does not limit the "validity" of  the promise or the refusal

Comment: In the *specific* context, it's unlikely you could make a case for either version being "stronger", or there being some other nuance of difference. But in something like *I invited her but she **isn't coming / won't come***, the ***won't*** version could more strongly imply "volitional **refusal**", whereas the ***isn't*** version might be far more neutral (her not coming being a matter of happenstance rather than an emphatic decision not to attend for some strongly-held reason).